# How can I fix this "IndentationError" in this Python code?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a small Python script for data mining and am getting the following error.

**Error:**

```
File "prediction.py", line 10
    data=pd.read_csv(file_name)
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

How can I fix it?

**My Code:**

```
    # Required Packages
    import csv
    import sys
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

    # Function to get data
    def get_data(file_name):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    flash_x_parameter = []
    flash_y_parameter = []
    arrow_x_parameter = []
    arrow_y_parameter = []
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in zip(data[‘flash_episode_number’], data[‘flash_us_viewers’], data[‘arrow_episode_number’], data[‘arrow_us_viewers’]):
    flash_x_parameter.append([float(x1)])
    flash_y_parameter.append(float(y1))
    arrow_x_parameter.append([float(x2)])
    arrow_y_parameter.append(float(y2))
    return flash_x_parameter, flash_y_parameter, arrow_x_parameter, arrow_y_parameter

    # Function to know which Tv show will have more viewers
    def more_viewers(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    regr1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr1.fit(x1, y1)
    predicted_value1 = regr1.predict(9)
    print predicted_value1
    regr2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr2.fit(x2, y2)
    predicted_value2 = regr2.predict(9)

    #print predicted_value1
    #print predicted_value2
    if predicted_value1 > predicted_value2:
    print "The Flash Tv Show will have more viewers for next week"
    else:
    print "Arrow Tv Show will have more viewers for next week"
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = get_data(‘input.csv’)
    #print x1, y1, x2, y2
    more_viewers(x1, y1, x2, y2)`
```

Comment: Try to *understand* code (and syntax) before running code thst you copy&pasted.

Comment: copy&paster not works in python.

Comment: The reason might be copying from a website that doesn't render code correctly (if even the HTML source is indented correctly).

Comment: There must be many, many duplicates. What is the canonical question?

Comment: The "Related" column shows many very high-scored Python questions, but none of them are even remotely related to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation matters in Python.

You're getting the error because you need to indent at the 10th line around your function definition:

```
# Function to get data
def get_data(file_name):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    flash_x_parameter = []
    flash_y_parameter = []
    ...
```

Comment: According to PEP8, I think you should using 4 spaces instead of 2.   :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you have to indent code for any nested block so python can recognize what belongs to global code, function code and any inner block code:

```
def get_data(file_name):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    ....
global code again
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of the indenting issue. Please read the docs for PEP8 [[docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)].

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
>
> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent [6] . When using a hanging indent
>   the following should be considered; there should be no arguments on
>   the first line and further indentation should be used to clearly
>   distinguish itself as a continuation line.

```
# Required Packages
import csv
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn
import datasets, linear_model

# Function to get data
def get_data(file_name):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    flash_x_parameter = []
    flash_y_parameter = []
    arrow_x_parameter = []
    arrow_y_parameter = []
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in zip(data[‘flash_episode_number’], data[‘flash_us_viewers’], data[‘arrow_episode_number’], data[‘arrow_us_viewers’]):
        flash_x_parameter.append([float(x1)])
    flash_y_parameter.append(float(y1))
    arrow_x_parameter.append([float(x2)])
    arrow_y_parameter.append(float(y2))
    return flash_x_parameter, flash_y_parameter, arrow_x_parameter, arrow_y_parameter

# Function to know which Tv show will have more viewers
def more_viewers(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    regr1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr1.fit(x1, y1)
    predicted_value1 = regr1.predict(9)
    print predicted_value1
    regr2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    regr2.fit(x2, y2)
    predicted_value2 = regr2.predict(9)

    # print predicted_value1# print predicted_value2
    if predicted_value1 > predicted_value2:
        print "The Flash Tv Show will have more viewers for next week"
    else :
        print "Arrow Tv Show will have more viewers for next week"
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = get_data(‘input.csv’)# print x1, y1, x2, y2
    more_viewers(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```